# List all US State names that have any two consecutive vowels (a, e, i, o, u). using the character vector state.name?

Tags: regex, grep

This is what I have but it returns all 50 states

```
grep("[a]|[i]|[o]|[u]",state.name, value=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
grep("[aeiou]{2}", state.name, value=TRUE)
```

Comment: Nitpicking:  if the OP wants "at least 2 consecutive," then `{2,}` is appropriate.  Yeah,  I know,  it's only Hawaii.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft well his question says "any two," and since there are no states with three consecutive vowels (at least if we assume he's talking about the United States, because "state" could have other meanings) I thought this would work nicely.

Comment: Hawaii.  Louisiana.   And my first comment was incorrect (sloppy thinking about regexp rules).  Use this:  `Rgames> grep("[aeiou]{,2}", state.name, value=TRUE)->state2;`
`Rgames> state2[!state2%in% grep("[aeiou]{3,}",state2,value=TRUE)] ` .There's got to be some regexp which says "find only vowel-vowel-!vowel" that isn't as clunky as [aeiou][aeiou][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz] :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft ah yes, `{,2}` -- and good point about the 3 consecutive vowels.  This is why I'm a software developer, not a professional speller.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft if you're looking for "vowel-vowel-!vowel", try `'[aeiou]{2}[^aeiou]'`

Comment: @nullrevolution that still matches `Louisiana`

Comment: @nullrevolution  I thought of that, but the problem is that, in a string of 3 vowels, the final two vowels match your pattern.